# launchDarkly getting TypeError: URL is not a constructor

Tags: next.js13, react-typescript, launchdarkly

I'm tring to get passed this error and can't seem to. This is the line I'm getting it on.

```
const client: LDClient = LaunchDarkly.init(key);
```

I'm using typescript, NextJS.
I'm using react-client-sdk version 3.0.10 and node-server-sdk version 7.0.3 of LaunchDarkly.

Comment: you should create minimial reproducible code sample

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did to get past this error.

```
export async function getClient(): Promise<LaunchDarkly.LDClient> {
  const client = LaunchDarkly.init(process.env.LAUNCHDARKLY_SDK_KEY!);
  await client.waitForInitialization();
  return client;
}
```